# Linux doesn't boot after update-grub

Tags: boot, grub, elementary-os

I had a problem with my HDMI without sound and I found this fix.

```
Edit /etc/default/grub and change this line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

to this line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.audio=1"

Now run "sudo update-grub", then reboot your computer.
```

Now, the boot stuck in a file systems check. Each time it's stucked in a different message. Sometimes, about bluetooth, others for network monitor etc. I cannot open Linux from recovery and from older versions, each one stuck in a black screen.

I cannot access my pc and if I will not find a sollution soon, I will turn to a clean install with losing all my data :(

Comment: Just follow the instructions here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492/48083. Except, before you do the `update-grub` again remove the offending option from your `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: If I am not wrong, I have access to grub. I can see all the options including windows 8 as a dual boot. The problem on the links seems to be without a grub at all. Right?

Comment: What you need to do is run `update-grub` again after you have removed `radeon.audio=1` (assuming this *is* what caused the problem). The only way for you to do this if you cannot boot is to boot from a live CD/USB drive and run the commands inside a `chroot` environment, as described in detail the linked answer. You can skip step 4 and the `grub-install` part of step 5, but running them won't do any harm. Just make sure you get the correct partition as described and **do not** blindly copy the commands.

Answer (score 3):

If you can access the grub (as can be read in the comments), just press <kbd>E</kbd> look for the line starting with `linux` and ending in `quiet splash radeon.audio=1`, like this:

```
linux   /vmlinuz-3.13-1-amd64 root=UUID=cead26d6-08f4-4894-ac78-a9a4ce59f773 ro initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet splash radeon.audio=1
```

and remove the offending parameter. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot the system. After that, just editing the `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub` should be a permanent fix (or reversion) of whatever you have done.

Comment: I tried it but the boot stack there again.