# Why do I get dropped into a GRUB rescue console?

Tags: fedora, grub2, boot-loader, xen, crash

I've been setting up my environment on a fedora 20 64bit, the last week. After a restart tonight I am unable to boot into my system. It boots into this terminal/prompt and it says:

```
 [ Minimal bash-like editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible completions of a device/filename. ]

grub>
```

I've tried to rescue the system, with the dvd, but no luck. I have installed a lot of software and I would rather not have to do it for the third time this week, last crash was because I installed grub2 and made some configurations, to include xen hypervisor support in the bootup  forgetting to turn "Secure boot" off in the bios.

Can anyone tell me what to do? What I can do.

Comment: Does http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109464/4671 help?

Comment: Something either screwed up your `grub.conf` or perhaps moved the disks around (my BIOS decided to switch C and D...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED: Jíbbí This post/answer had the fix:[How can I fix/install/reinstall grub?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/failed-boot-from-newly-made-linux-mint-hdd)

Thank you so much for that comment Faheem Mitha.

Kristjan

Comment: Good to know your problem is fixed. If you found a post useful, you are encouraged to upvote it. Additionally, you can accept your own answer. Then the question is marked as answered, which is a good thing for the site.