# How To Fix Grub Boot Error hd0 out of disk

Tags: debian, grub

After I updated Debian to Wheezy whenever I boot my computer I get `Grub boot error hd0 out of disk` and then a prompt comes up with `grub rescue>`.  So far I have been unable to find a solution by googleing.  When I run `grub-update` on a live system I get `bash: grub-update: command not found`.

Comment: Does http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109464/4671 help?

Comment: Not really as that person didn't have grub at all, whereas my problem is that I am getting a grub error.  Thanks for showing me that though.

Comment: Nevertheless, read the answer, not the question. It is highly likely that reinstalling grub will fix your error. For example, in the answer I explain how to run `update-grub` (grub-update is now called `update-grub`). I don't know what that particular error means but attempting to reinstall grub is probably a good idea.

Comment: @qsylalyn no, terdon's answer is basically about reinstalling grub if it doesn't work. the question itself is not that relevant perhaps

Comment: Thanks, how can I find where it is mounted?

Comment: Where what is mounted?