# GRUB fails to install to NVMe SSD - Debian Jessie 8.6

Tags: debian, grub2, ssd

I'm getting essentially the same error as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280440/grub-and-lilo-both-fail-to-install-to-nvme-hard-disk-when-installing-debian/286480#286480?newreg=7e6e5d41ed4e43bbab7ce4fd14d523e6) except when I try to do the proposed solution, at this step:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/nvme0n1
```

I get this error:

```
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
```

This is a clean install using an ASRock motherboard with the Z170 chipset, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Is nvme0n1p1, not nvme0n1, your ESP? p1 is first partition. And is it mounted in fstab with correct UUID? Post this in question above: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,UUID,mountpoint`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an Asus Z170 motherboard. FWIW, I installed a 'testing' build of Debian (currently Alpha 8 of Stretch) over a Windows 10 install and dual-boot etc. is working great, so far.

Info here: [https://www.debian.org/releases/testing/](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/)

Please note that this is not a 'stable' release. Here are some notes about using a 'testing' release: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting

Answer (score 0):

Can you see /dev/nvme0n1 ?

```
 ls -l /dev/nvme0n1
```

If not, do you have the nvme-cli package installed?
Once installed, you should be able to continue.