# OpenSUSE 13.1 Cannot Find a Bootable Device After Update

Tags: boot, grub2, opensuse, crash

I have just installed OpenSUSE 13.1 on a computer. After that, I did a `zypper update` and a reboot and the computer would not boot. The error message was something like `"no bootable device found"`. I use grub2 with EFI Support as boot loader and I suppose that the error message means that grub cannot find the right partition. My partitions are setup like this. (What I actually did here was reinstalling OpenSUSE and then updated again. However, I have not yet turned of the computer when I get the following output)

```
computer-name:~ # fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 240.1 GB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
1         2048       321535    156M  EFI System      primary
2       321536      4530175      2G  Microsoft basic primary
3      4530176     46475263     20G  EFI System      primary
4     46475264    468860927  201.4G  Microsoft basic primary
computer-name:~ # df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       20510716 4407320  15038440  23% /
devtmpfs         8182632      40   8182592   1% /dev
tmpfs            8195504      80   8195424   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            8195504    6980   8188524   1% /run
tmpfs            8195504       0   8195504   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            8195504    6980   8188524   1% /var/lock
tmpfs            8195504    6980   8188524   1% /var/run
/dev/sda1         159564     128    159436   1% /boot/efi
```

I know that there are plenty of questions that are similar to this one, for example [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/how-can-i-fix-install-reinstall-grub/109492#109492) but I find no question that I think really fits my particular issue, that I can understand. Does anyone know how to fix this issue (preferably at the current state before rebooting, but any working solution would be gladly accepted)?

Comment: Have you tried `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`?

Comment: Just like that? With nothing else? Should I do it before or after I reboot?

Comment: @eyoung100 Ok I tried that, but it did not work. However, when I now entered the rescue mode, I could not find the file. `/boot/grub2/` was empty. Should I try to create a file grub.cfg by running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` once more?

Comment: @eyoung100 however, I must add that looking into the grub shell, I see find the file under (hd0,2).

Comment: You should not create that by hand.  Read [this ActiveDoc](https://activedoc.opensuse.org/book/opensuse-reference/chapter-10-the-boot-loader-grub2)  The default has changed.

Comment: @eyoung100 I see, but the question was rather, should I do this in rescue mode? Or maybe in grub?

Comment: @eyoung100 also, the provided link seems to assume that I can start opensuse, since the first action `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` did not work I am afraid I need to do this from the rescue system. Do you have an idea how I should continue from there (or from grub).

Comment: I would attempt the ActiveDoc Solution from a LiveCD.  The issue here is that OpenSUSE did not store the Grub2 Items in the default Location.  As such you must use the tool OpenSUSE prefers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it seemed to be a compatibility problem with the BIOS. I updated the BIOS and after that all went through just fine.