# Minimal BASH like line editing is supported

Tags: fedora, windows, grub2, grub

I have Fedora 23 dual boot with Windows 10. Suddenly, I'm not able to see the normal GRUB menu to go into either Fedora or Windows.

I've seen the question and answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/how-can-i-fix-install-reinstall-grub) but I'm already stuck at step 1.

My file system is as follows:

```
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                3.9G  176K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                3.9G  1.7M  3.9G   1% /run
tmpfs                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1             15G  4.7G  9.9G  33% /run/initramfs/live
/dev/mapper/live-rw  5.8G  3.8G  2.0G  66% /
tmpfs                3.9G   24K  3.9G   1% /tmp
vartmp               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /var/tmp
varcacheyum          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /var/cache/yum
tmpfs                788M   28K  788M   1% /run/user/1000
```

What should I do now?

I've got the following at GRUB prompt:

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hdp,gpt11) (hd0,gpt10) (hd0,gpt9)...(hd0,gpt1) (lvm,fedora-root) (lvm,fedora-home) (lvm,fedora-swap)
```