# Wireless not working on Linux Mint Live CD, I need internet connection to fix python because I removed it in Linux Gnome

Tags: wifi, python, live-usb, internet

This is was the actual [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363700/sudo-apt-get-remove-python-gnome-did-not-boot-tried-dpkg-unpack-deb) at first

Now I booted with Linux Mint (my broken OS is Linux Gnome) and still no internet connection. I need it to repair python and get my OS up and running again. Sadly, I can't connect the lan cable because I moved to the UK three months ago and the router hasn't got the standard lan cable.

After `lspci -nn | grep 0280` this is what I get:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
```

Comment: It is better to get an internet connection , because you need to install tow packages `linux-headers` and the `bcmwl-kernel-source` to get the wifi working on the broadcom wifi card. Try to get internet connection like smartphone tethering through USB , 3G, 4G... or use a wifi usb supportd by your kernel version