# grub2 error disk 'hd0,msdos1' not found, ls shows no disk

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, grub2, boot-loader

I have googled a lot for this problem.
I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/how-can-i-fix-install-reinstall-grub),
but it didn't solve my problem.
Other solutions suggest me to reinstall grub (run grub-install), which didn't work either.

Here is what I am doing: (my grub version is 2.02)

1. I use grub2-mkrescue to make my X.iso
2. I boot a VMWareWorkstation virtual machine, which has a 1.0GB SATA disk, from X.iso
3. I install X.iso on disk, the details are:

3.1. erase /dev/sda in case there are old partitions on it:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=1`

3.2. Create 3 primary partitions on /dev/sda as dev/sda1,sda2,sda3 (the size is 100M, 30M and 70M),
and toggle sda1 to be bootable

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1024 MB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
130 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Device  Boot StartCHS    EndCHS        StartLBA     EndLBA    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1 *  0,1,1       12,191,50           63     204862     204800  100M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2    12,191,51   16,147,2        204863     266302      61440 30.0M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3    16,147,3    25,127,37       266303     409662     143360 70.0M 83 Linux
```

3.3. Format the 3 partitions as ext2, and mount /dev/sda1

```
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda1
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda2
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda3
ROOTFS_PATH=/var/.rootfs
mkdir $ROOTFS_PATH
mount /dev/sda1 $ROOTFS_PATH
```

3.4 copy files...

```
for i in bzImage initrd.img vmlinuz-*; do
    cp -rf /boot/$i $ROOTFS_PATH/boot
done
cp -f /boot/grub/device.map $ROOTFS_PATH/boot/grub/device.map
for i in init linuxrc; do
    cp -rf /$i $ROOTFS_PATH
done
for i in bin etc lib sbin share usr; do
    cp -a /$i $ROOTFS_PATH
done
for i in dev var proc sys tmp data log; do
    mkdir -p $ROOTFS_PATH/$i
done
```

3.5 Install grub and make grub config file

```
chroot $ROOTFS_PATH <<EOF
mount -a
mdev -s
grub-install $tdisk
grub-install --recheck $tdisk
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
exit
EOF
```

4. reboot

It says:

```
.
error: disk 'hd0,msdos1' not found
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

And the most strange thing is that `ls` command shows nothing in grub-rescue cli
---- as someone says, it should show disk list.

[image: error after reboot]

Comment: Check your USB, for me it was the USB is not working properly because it's old and dusty

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -f /boot/grub/device.map $ROOTFS_PATH/boot/grub/device.map
```

So, you copied the GRUB `device.map` file from the GRUB rescue ISO image to your disk?
It might be forcing `grub-install` to associate the GRUB device identifier `hd0` with a disk device other than `/dev/sda`.

Before running `grub-install`, verify that the `device.map` file actually associates `hd0` with the disk you're installing GRUB to (i.e. `/dev/sda` in your case).

Also, why are you doing all this? It looks like you're trying to make a `grub2-mkrescue` VM image that might be useable in rescuing some other VM that has lost its bootloader - is that what you're planning to do? If so, simply booting the problem VM using an ISO image of any Live CD/DVD Linux distribution would give you a more extensive set of tools and more comfortable environment for fixing your original problem, whether it's a missing bootloader or something else.

If you specifically need `grub2-mkrescue`, you already have your `X.iso` - why you are trying to convert it to a virtual-disk-based installation?

Comment: thanks for your reply. What I'm trying is to build a very small x86 Linux distro with only a few feature.  Just like other Linux distro, Ubuntu,CentOS - Someone download a ubuntu-x.iso, boot from it and install it into the disk.That's what I want.

Comment: I want a disk-based installation, instead of a virtual-disk-based installation. However, I'm testing it on the virtual machine, before a real machine.

Comment: As [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Device-map.html) says: _If the device map file does not exist, then the GRUB utilities will assume a temporary device map on the fly. This is often good enough, particularly in the common case of single-disk systems._ So I delete `device.map` from X.iso and donot copy it when installing, But the problem remained the same. Any other suggestions?