# kernel panic not syncing unknownblock (0,0) for Mint & Kali after installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, kali-linux, grub2, mbr

This is what my disk looks like right now :

[image: Windows 11 disk management]

I have installed Windows 11 on the PC.
I then decided to install Kali Linux to learn cybersecurity (*please don't tell me "if you're asking this question, you shouldn't be installing Kali*"). Everything was working fine, I could boot easily, no problem

But I also want to have a general purpose Linux, so I chose Linux Mint.

I downloaded the installer, launched it, it didn't leave me the choice to install GRUB or not (I didn't want to, I was pretty sure it was going to mess things up).

After restart, GRUB changed (the Kali theme is gone), Windows boots up fine, but neither Kali, nor Mint boot up : the output the well known error on Internet :

Kernel Panic, not syncing, cannot mount unknownblock(0,0) or something along those lines.

Other posts say to boot off an older kernel, but I don't have any option in `Advanced Options`, on `recovery mode`...

My system is CSM, my partitioning table MBR. I can select UEFI in the BIOS, but that just results in a simple `insert disk into drive`

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Comment: Note that the standard advice isn't "you shouldn't be using Kali if you need to ask the question", it is "Kali is not a learning tool, so this will only make it much harder and more complicated for you to learn". Just saying.

Comment: Try booting off of a live installation medium (Mint's will do) and following the steps here: [How can I fix/install/reinstall grub?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109492). Does that sort it out?

Comment: @terdon thanks, i'll try that tonight and keep you informed

Comment: Hummm... Five primary partition with MBR? How?

Comment: @K-att- hum, no in fact, the first 3 are grouped in 1 logical partition, according to the live gparted when I installed Mint ; it's just Windows not showing them...

Comment: Can you explain how can you convert the physical partition into the logical? It's exciting.

Comment: Hum, i don't know, Kali must have done it during installation...

Comment: Ok. You told me earlier, the linux mint install grouped the partition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144442/discussion-between-silloky-and-k-att).